# Convert Parallels VM to Virtual PC 2007 VM

Tags: virtualization, virtual-pc, parallels

I'd like to convert a Parallels Virtual Machine image on my mac into an image usable by Virtual PC 2007.  Does anyone know how to do that, or if it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like qemu-img from [qemu](http://bellard.org/qemu/) can do this, at least looking at its commandline help on a Ubuntu 8.04 machine where it claims support for, among others, the "parallels" and the "vpc" format.

Have not tried myself, though. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Windows image, I would mount the VM using a tool like [SmartVDK](http://www.prowesscorp.com/support/help/smartdeploy_vdc/Welcome_to_SmartVDK_v1.0.htm), then capture the VM with ImageX to a WIM file.  You can then mount a blank VHD with SmartVDK and apply the image using ImageX /APPLY.

The qemu-img tool is better if you're performing the conversion on a Mac or Linux machine.

Keep in mind that you will probably encounter difficulties booting the drive if the drive serials have changed.  Also, the hardware will be different.  It is often better to build a new image and then to mount the converted drive, copying over anything else you need.